# jQuery find id after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my structure:

**Person.html**

```
...
<script src="../../js/site.js"></script>
...
<a id="findPersonById" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary">
Find person by id</a>
...
<div id="person-result">results div</div>
```

**Site.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  privateFunction();
});
...
$('#findPersonById').click(function () {
  $("#person-result").load('/person/find #inside-container');
});
...
```

**/person/find**

```
<script src="../../js/site.js"></script>
...
<div class="container">
<div id="inside-container">
    <br/>
    <form id="personFindByIdForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">PERSON'S ID</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id"/>
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Find</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="find-result">res-div</div>
</div>
```

So, first of all I'm finding `#findPersonById` and loading `/person/find #inside-container` in the `#person-result`. It works. My next step was about to find two ids `#personFindByIdForm` and `#find-result`. I can't do it since document is already loaded if I'm right. How could I do this ?
And the second question - if I add any js code into the div that will be loaded into another div, will that js code run (why is it not running)?
Like:

```
$("#div-2").load('/any-url #div-1');
<div id='div-1'>
  <script>console.log('Any JS')</script>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: About your second question, it doesn't work because this script would be executed on the load. As your page has been already loaded, it doesn't do anything. If it was another type of script, like $('xxxx').click({...}), it would

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make sure the items are loaded this way:

```
$("#div-2").load('/any-url #div-1', function(){
     //here all the items loaded will be accessible

});
```